# Arithmetic operations on a particular column of a CSV file in Bash

Tags: bash, bash-script

I am having a file whose contents are as follows:

```
A,10,20,30,40,50
B,20,40,10,30,60
C,30,50,20,40,10
D,40,50,20,10,30
```

I wish to perform some arithmetic operation (say Division by 10) on a particular column (say Column 3) of above CSV file. So that, it reads :

```
A,10,2,30,40,50
B,20,4,10,30,60
C,30,5,20,40,10
D,40,5,20,10,30
```

How can this be done?

Comment: If your file is really this simple, you already seem to have the answer. If your CSV file is more complex (e.g. with values quoted and spanning multiple lines), parsing using bash is going to be fragile at best. CSV parsing is best done with some specialised package for Perl or Python to prevent problems with real CSV files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
% awk -F , -v OFS=, '$3/=10' <file
A,10,2,30,40,50
B,20,4,10,30,60
C,30,5,20,40,10
D,40,5,20,10,30
```

Comment: I think you missed that the author wants a solution using bash, not awk.

Comment: @Anthon I doubt that there is casual (non exotic hardware) situation where environment has full bash (not sh) implementation and is limited not to use awk.

Comment: @Anthon Well, that is what the asker asked litterally , but not what he wanted, considering the answer is accepted.

Comment: @Bernhard There have been multiple questions on U&L where the OP would comment on such an answer with something like: what part of "in bash" do you not understand. I just tried to warn the answerer, who might have misread the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want to do it in bash, you can:

```
$ while IFS="," read a b c rest; do 
    printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n" $a $b $((c/10)) $rest; 
  done < file.csv 
A,10,2,30,40,50
B,20,4,10,30,60
C,30,5,20,40,10
D,40,5,20,10,30
```

While this works for simple integer arithmetic, bash cannot deal with floating point numbers so if you were to try an arithmetic operation that produced non-integers it would fail. Horribly. Bash is really not the best tool for the job here.

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller to divide the numbers in the 3rd field of the header-less CSV file by 10:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N put '$3 /= 10' file
A,10,2,30,40,50
B,20,4,10,30,60
C,30,5,20,40,10
D,40,5,20,10,30
```

This is fine if the CSV data does not contain headers. If it does, we can use the named headers:

```bash
$ cat file
Alpha,Number,Medium,Ch,Beets,Returns
A,10,20,30,40,50
B,20,40,10,30,60
C,30,50,20,40,10
D,40,50,20,10,30
```

```bash
$ mlr --csv put '$Medium /= 10' file
Alpha,Number,Medium,Ch,Beets,Returns
A,10,2,30,40,50
B,20,4,10,30,60
C,30,5,20,40,10
D,40,5,20,10,30
```

Note that we drop the `-N` option, as we now want to make use of the headers in the input, and also produce them in the output.